# rotating array until condition is met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know how to achieve this, but it doesn't seem like the ruby way of doing it.

I have a hash of days in week:

```
DAYS = {
1 => "Monday",
2 => "Tuesday",
3 => "Wednesday",
4 => "Thursday",
5 => "Friday",
6 => "Saturday",
7 => "Sunday"}
```

(there is probably some rails helper for this, but I've implemented it the fastest way I could think of)

Now I would like to create an array where the first element is today, and the other days should remain ordered.

Here's this array

```
 def day_keys
    # proper sorting of days, start with today and then continue
    day_array = (1..7).to_a
    loop do
      break if day_array.first == Time.now.wday
      day_array.rotate!
    end
    day_array
  end
```

It's Friday today, so it returns `[5,6,7,1,2,3,4]`. After this I map the values from this array with the keys from the `DAYS` hash to find the day names.

Solution seems pretty rough to me, so I would like to hear some ideas on how to implement this. I've spent some time looking at `Array#cycle` and `Enumerable#inject` but nothing seems to fit my needs.

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to achieve, in the context of your app? There may be no need at all to do this.

Comment: This is used in a helper that renders a calendar. I need a calendar in a form of table that displays hours of a day in a rows and days in week in columns. I couldn't find any good gems for this so I've decided to build it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:   `((Time.now.wday)..(Time.now.wday+6)).collect{|i| ((i-1) % 7) +1}`

If you are in rails, you have a few more helpers. This yields an array of Dates:

```
 ((Time.now.to_date)..(6.days.from_now.to_date)).collect{|i| i}
```

And if you want the day name, it's just a slight modification

```
 ((Time.now.to_date)..(6.days.from_now.to_date)).collect{|i| i.strftime "%A"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work...

```
DAYS_HASH = { 'Mon' => 1,
'Tue', => 2,
'Wed', => 3,
'Thu', => 4,
'Fri', => 5 }

DAYS_ARY = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri']

def days(start)
  DAYS_ARRAY.rotate(start-1)
end
```

> days(DAYS_HASH['Wed'])

```
=> ['Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Mon', 'Tue']
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have ruby 1.8.7

```
day_array.index(Time.now.wday).times do day_array.push(day_array.shift) end
```

if you have ruby 1.9.2

```
day_array.index(Time.now.wday).times do day_array.rotate end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'
today = Date.today
p (today..today+6).map{|day| Date::DAYNAMES[day.wday]}
#=>["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"]
```